# Two buttons that toggle with background-position changes with a result in an Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, onclick, toggle

How to create a jQuery/javascript function to:

1. Insert its value into an input box (male/female)
2. Change its background and the background of its sibling button to show whether it's active?

Here is my HTML for a start:

```
<input type="button" class="ts" id="female" onclick="???????????" />
<input type="button" class="ts" id="male"   onclick="???????????" />

<input class="req-string bx long" type="text" id="gender" name="gender" />
```

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Where is your background defined? What do you mean by on/off state?

Comment: It's still very hard to understand. You can take out "Ajax" since that has nothing to do with the solution, also confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/hMheQ/2/) which will direct you on the right path. It doesn't do what you are asking, but you will get the idea.

The code below would disable the other button: if you click on "female" it will disable "male" and vice-versa.

```
$(function() {

  $('#female').click(function() {     

    // place text ("male" or "female") in an input 
    $('#gender').val('female');

    $('#female').css({background:'green'});
    $('#male').css({background:'red'});
  });

  $('#male').click(function() {      

    // place text ("male" or "female") in an input 
    $('#gender').val('male');

    // emulates the button being toggled
    $('#female').css({background:'red'});
    $('#male').css({background:'green'});
  });

});​
```

Comment: for the onclick button, how would I make a button?

Comment: Forget about the onlick attribute on the input tag, use the jQuery click. It is a cleaner separation of UI code (the HTML) and logic (the JavaScript). It makes reading each a bit easier.

Comment: When I run the script it works, but the page refreshes and I loose the result.

Comment: Why would clicking on the inputs refresh the screen?

Comment: Perhaps it is your input "type" which can be set to submit?

Comment: Hi, if you had your problem solved you might consider my answer as correct